# I want to time the execution of these two scripts

Tags: javascript

u found a javascript that used external scripts and one that embeds them. I want to time the execution of both scripts to see how long they take.

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_whereto

https://www.w3schools.com/js/tryit.asp?filename=tryjs_whereto_external

Comment: what did you try ? share us the code.

Answer (score 1):

Like this

```
var t0 = performance.now();
myfunction('hi');
var t1 = performance.now();
console.log("Call to doSomething took " + (t1 - t0) + " milliseconds.");  


function myfunction(string){
    console.log(string);
}
```

Comment: doesnt work https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FDZIV0CL4X88

Comment: it does, but myfunction() wasn't defined

Comment: it is, in the .js file